# fluent validation add validation errors mannually and rethrow errors

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have defined an:

```
IValidator<SomeClass> _myValidator
```

I can do:

```
_myValidator.ValidateAndThrow(someObject);
```

instead I would like to:

```
var errors = _myValidator.Validate(entity);
```

add some errors manually and then re-throw the errors. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store the errors in a variable, you'll have to return the error, or a list of errors, instead of throwing them.

```
IList<Exception> ValidateAndThrow(object someObject){

    IList<Exception> errors = new List<Exception>();

    try{
        SomethingGoesWrong();
    } catch (Exception e){
        errors.Add(e);
    }

    return errors;
}
```

Comment: Just realised that myself. I use something along those lines: ValidationFailure test = new ValidationFailure("bla", "bla");
errors.Add(test);

throw new ValidationException(errors);